# Magento2 SOMETIME The order confirmation email is not sent

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-email

When an order is placed and payed, usually all emails are sent (confirmation to the customer and bcc to addresses specified in configuration.. 'Send Order Email Copy To' ) but I have two cases in wich the email is not sent.
All is configured correctly and usually running properly, no logs related in the system log, debug.log or exception.log.

Where I can find info about this failure? Are there any table in the db to check?

The only information I have found is in sales_order where fields email_sent and **send_email** are both null, usually = 1.

**Why send_email is null?**

I cannot find any checkbox during the ceckout process to not receive the order email confirmation.

In Magento 1.9 there was the table core_email_queue. In Magento 2?

Thanks,
Ale

Comment: Are you able to replicate it, is it something to do with checking out as a guest or only when logged in etc?

Comment: No, I can't replicate it. It happens 2 times and both customers were guests. For Others guest customers there were no problem for sending email confirmation.

Comment: I'm having he same issue. It only happens when I place an order through the backend 'Place Order for a Customer' feature. I'm using Magento 2.1.7. When I place an order through the API it works out fine. 

Magento has been hugely inconsistent with this and other bugs. I'm not really happy with it and will probably not use it again in the future.

Comment: same issue here....